# Преобразование части из байт в строку по длинне строки

Tags: javascript

Есть ArrayBuffer, который читается через DataView

```js
var arrayBuffer = (... получено с сервера)
var view = new DataView(arrayBuffer);

var offset = 0;

var stringLength = view.getUint8(offset); //длина строки является одним байтом
offset++;

var value = //прочитать строку из байт по её длине. (при этом в байтах останется ещё информация, которая не относится к строке)
```

То есть с сервера приходит длина строки, и за длиной идёт сама строка, и за строкой идёт ещё информация, например картинка. Взять длину строки как длину байт нельзя, ведь есть символы из нескольких байт. Клиент в браузере. Не NodeJS

Comment: Так может и длина записана в байтах, а не в символах?

Comment: @AlexeyTen нет, длина строки в символах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передавать байты в [TextDecoder.decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/decode) по одному пока не накопится строка требуемой длины. Не самое быстрое решение, но показывает идею:

```js
const encode = s => new TextEncoder().encode(s).buffer;

const decode = (buffer, n) => {
    const td = new TextDecoder();
    let s = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.byteLength; ++i) {
        s += td.decode(new DataView(buffer, i, 1), {stream: true});
        if (s.length >= n) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return s;
};

const test = (s, n) => {
    console.log();
    console.log('source', s);
    const b = encode(s);
    console.log('buffer', new Uint8Array(b));
    console.log('result', decode(b, n));
}

test('Hello!', 3);
test('Привет!', 3);
```

Вариант с радикально меньшим количеством вызовов декодера. Быстрее работает на длинных строках. Функция принимает позицию начального байта строки, возвращает строку и место где строка закончилась:

```
const decode = (buffer, start, n) => {
    const td = new TextDecoder();
    let s = '';
    let i = start;
    while (i < buffer.byteLength && s.length < n) {
        const len = Math.min(n - s.length, buffer.byteLength - i);
        s += td.decode(new DataView(buffer, i, len), {stream: true});
        i += len;
    }
    return [s, i];
};
```